# Why PyCharm don't find the folder on the project?

Tags: python, directory, pycharm, anaconda, jupyter

I have a problem with a data folder, I try to run a cell in a jupyter notebook which have a folder path.
In data folder there is a csv.
I deleted the .idea folder but doesn't work, like in other questions.

[image: 1]